Websocket connection with STOMP compat client using springboot and angular
I am trying to connect the frontend to the backend using websockets with compatclient but the web server displays the above error when inspecting. i have tried to fix it but nothing seems to be working.
The connection is to a form that takes 4 parameters and passes it to the database. The data is stored in the database properly when I used Postman.
It says that the Websocket is not defined in the console.
connect.service.ts:17 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/ws' failed:

is shown in the web browser when inspecting.
The code files are shown below.
This is my Web socket Configuration class
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue"); // destination prefix for receiving messages
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app"); // prefix for sending messages
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        // Register the WebSocket endpoint
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200/").withSockJS();
    }
}


This is the Controller class for the websocket
package com.example.Coursework1_BE.WebSocket;

import com.example.Coursework1_BE.Configuration;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.Coursework1_BE.Repositories.ConfigurationRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller

public class WSController {
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationRepo configurationRepo;

    @GetMapping("/configuration")
    @SendTo("/topic/config")
    public Configuration saveConfig( Configuration config){
        return configurationRepo.save(config);
    }
}

This is the service file
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CompatClient, Stomp, Frame } from '@stomp/stompjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})


export class WebSocketService {
  private stompClient: CompatClient | null = null;

  constructor() {}

  initWebSocket(): void {
    // Create a native WebSocket endpoint
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000/ws');

    // Initialize CompatClient using native WebSocket
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);

    // Disable debugging (optional, for cleaner logs)
    this.stompClient.debug = () => {};

    // Connect and configure the CompatClient
    this.stompClient.connect(
      {}, // headers
      (frame: Frame) => {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);

        // Subscribe to a topic
        this.stompClient?.subscribe('/topic/updates', (message) => {
          console.log('Received message:', message.body);
        });
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.error('STOMP error:', error);
      }
    );
  }

  sendMessage(destination: string, message: any): void {
    if (this.stompClient && this.stompClient.connected) {
      this.stompClient.send(destination, {}, JSON.stringify(message));
    } else {
      console.error('STOMP client is not connected.');
    }
  }

  disconnect(): void {
    if (this.stompClient && this.stompClient.connected) {
      this.stompClient.disconnect(() => {
        console.log('Disconnected');
      });
    }
  }
}


and this is the component file
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketService } from '../services/connect.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-configuration-form',
  templateUrl: './configuration-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./configuration-form.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports:[FormsModule, CommonModule]
})


export class ConfigurationFormComponent implements OnInit {
  data = {
    totaltickets: '',
    ticketreleaserate: '',
    customerretrievalrate: '',
    maxcapacity: '',
  };

  constructor(private websocketService: WebSocketService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Initialize WebSocket connection
    this.websocketService.initWebSocket();
  }

  submitForm(): void {
    if (this.isValidForm()) {
      this.websocketService.sendMessage('/app/config', this.data);
      console.log('Form submitted:', this.data);
    } else {
      console.error('Form is invalid. Please fill all fields.');
    }
  }

  isValidForm(): boolean {
    return (
      this.data.totaltickets.trim() !== '' &&
      this.data.ticketreleaserate.trim() !== '' &&
      this.data.customerretrievalrate.trim() !== '' &&
      this.data.maxcapacity.trim() !== ''
    );
  }
}


